# Função ZipArchive do PHP não funciona com mais de um arquivo

Tags: php, arquivo-zip

O código é o seguinte:

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$criou = $zip->open("download.zip", ZipArchive::CREATE);
if ($criou === true){

    $diretorio = UPLOAD_DIR . 'produto/small/';

    foreach ($imagens as $imagem) {
        $zip->addFile($diretorio . $imagem->arquivo . '.' . $imagem->extensao, $imagem->arquivo . '.' . $imagem->extensao);
        echo $diretorio . $imagem->arquivo . '.' . $imagem->extensao;
        echo '<br />';
    }

    $zip->close();

}else {
    echo 'Erro: '.$criou;
}
```

O resultado do `echo` dentro do `foreach` é apresentado perfeitamente, sem erros, da seguinte forma:

```
/site/public/uploads/produto/small/BN-260-A.jpg
/site/public/uploads/produto/small/BN-260-B.jpg
/site/public/uploads/produto/small/BN-261.jpg
/site/public/uploads/produto/small/BN-373.png
/site/public/uploads/produto/small/BN-10125-A.jpg
```

Entretanto, o arquivo baixado gera um loop com um arquivo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Importante verificar se o arquivo está realmente sendo gravado na íntegra ao fechar:

```
if ( $zip->close() ) {
   echo 'Arquivo fechado com sucesso';
} else {
   echo 'Problemas no fechamento';
}
```

Outro passo relevante é ter a certeza de que o arquivo existe e é legível:

```
foreach ($imagens as $imagem) {
   $caminho_relativo = $imagem->arquivo.'.'.$imagem->extensao;
   $caminho_absoluto = $diretorio.$caminho_relativo;
   if ( file_exists( $caminho_absoluto ) && is_readable( $caminho_absoluto ) ) {
      $zip->addFile( $caminho_absoluto, $caminho_relativo );
      echo $caminho_absoluto.' adicionado<br />';
   else {
      echo $caminho_absoluto.' com problemas<br />';
   }
}
```